# magento 1.9 picture of my product not Equal

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a problem
in home page or other page i have list of product Like other shoping site
in my site all picture Not the same size
please  see the upload picture

[image: picture not one size]

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered you in the other post !

1. Resize your product images with the same fonction like this :

   ```
   Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(150, 150)
   ```
2. Put this css property in your image product container :

   ```
   <div class="product-content">
       <div class="product-top">
           <img src="..." /> // your product image
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

   **CSS**

   ```
   .product-content .product-top img {
       min-height: 350px; //replace the 350px with the one you want
   }
   ```

Comment: I have this problem in category page
where is file of category page?

Comment: App/design/frontend/your package/your theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

Answer (score 0):

These are the standard generated magento product images.
It seems you uploaded images with differend sizes/formats.

If you want to set a exact size for this output, you can check your image sizes for small image here: `System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog` and check the tap for *Product Image*. Here you can set the sizes for base and small images for your products.

If the base/small image size is correct, you can edit the template file: `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` and change the code here `$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135);`

Add a value in resize(xxx) with the size you want.